# displaying records in ruby on rails using a conditional filter breaking down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I display all the records in a table if there is no `params[:subject_id]` sent, or filter the records that it will display if the `params[:subject_id]` is sent?.

So far I have a before filter in the pages controller to check if the `params[:subject_id]` were sent and creates an instance variable.

```
  private

  def find_subject
    if params[:subject_id]
      @subject = Subject.find_by_id(params[:subject_id])
    else
      @subject = Subject.all
    end
  end
```

problem is in the action when done like this `@pages` only stores the last record but won't break anything in the view.

```
  before_filter :find_subject

  def list
    @subject.each do |subject|
      @pages = Page.order("pages.position ASC").where(:subject_id => subject.id)
    end
  end
```

however if i do it like this

```
  def list
      @pages = Page.order("pages.position ASC").where(:subject_id => @subject.id)
  end
```

no records are returned the returned at all, when i check the output in the webrick console I see this

```
Subject Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `subjects`.* FROM `subjects` 
Page Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` WHERE `pages`.`subject_id` = 2186859380 ORDER BY pages.position ASC
```

Im not sure how its getting that id of `2186859380`

I have also tired it this way

```
  def list
    if @subject.object_id.nil?
      @pages = Page.order("pages.position ASC")
    else
      @pages = Page.order("pages.position ASC").where(:subject_id => @subject.object_id)
    end
  end
```

however this also throws some errors and breaks my view as well.

here is my view so you can get a complete picture

```
<div class="page list">
    <h2>Pages</h2>
<%= link_to "Add a new Page", {:action => "new", :subject_id => @subject.id}, :class => "action new" %>
    <table class="listing" summary="Pages List">
        <tr class="header">
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Page</th>
            <th>Visible</th>
            <th>Sections</th>
            <th>Permalink</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        <% @pages.each do |page| %>
        <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even") %>">
            <td><%= page.position %></td>
            <td><%= page.subject.name %></td>
            <td><%= page.name %></td>
            <td class="center"><%= page.visible ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
            <td class="center"><%= page.sections.size %></td>
            <td><%= page.permalink %></td>
            <td class="actions">
                <%= link_to("Sections", {:controller => "sections", :action => "list", :page_id => page.id}, :class => "action delete")%>
                <%= link_to("Show", {:action => "show", :id => page.id, :subject_id => @subject.id}, :class => "action show")%>
                <%= link_to("Edit", {:action => "edit", :id => page.id, :subject_id => @subject.id}, :class => "action edit")%>
                <%= link_to("Delete", {:action => "delete", :id => page.id, :subject_id => @subject.id}, :class => "action delete")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any help on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add a "s" to subject like here :

```
  private

  def find_subject
    if params[:subject_id]
      @subject = Subject.find_by_id(params[:subject_id])
    else
      @subjects = Subject.all
    end
  end
```

So now, you can do this :

```
def list
  if subjects
    @subject.each do |subject|
      @pages = Page.order("pages.position ASC").where(:subject_id => subject.id)
    end
  else
    @pages = Page.order("pages.position ASC").where(:subject_id => @subject.id)
  end
end
```

You could do something similar in your view...

Comment: thanks for the try this solutions can work but i would need to rewrite all of my views which is not what i wanted I was hoping for the `@subject` instance variable in my views to automatically get the right thing without my views having to do any of the checking or the need to have 2 different views.

Comment: also Im working on a solution but keep running into an error when trying to do this    at'subject.each do |subject|
      at'pages = Page.order("pages.position ASC").where(:subject_id => subject.id)
    end`

Comment: You view is strange. When the is many result you can't do that : `:subject_id => @subject.id`. If `@subject` is a collection you will have the is of the collection and it's not what you want. Which subject you want when you go to the new page form? You must to use a loop or a partial if you want a link for each subject.